# The subspace topology of $Y_u$($Y$ with upper topology) is strictly coarser than the one induced from $X$?

Tags: general-topology, order-theory, domain-theory

Let $(X,\leqslant )$ be a poset, we define the upper topology has the principle upper sets, that is upper sets of the form $\left \{ \uparrow x:x\in P\right \} $, as the subbase. We can define Alexandroff topology and Scott topology as well.

Let $Y$ be a subset of $X$. The subspace topology on $Y$ has as opens the subsets of $Y$ of the form $U\cap Y, U$ open in $X$.

The truth is subspace topologies of Alexandroff-discrete spaces are
again Alexandroff-discrete.(Easy to prove) and a subspace of a Scott space itself can not be a Scott space.([here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3082913/when-is-a-subspace-of-a-scott-space-itself-a-scott-space))

How to prove the topology of $Y_u$($Y$ with upper topology) is strictly coarser than the one(subspace topology) induced from $X$?

I will be very appreciate if anyone give an example.

Comment: The upper topology, as you defined it, is exactly the set of all upper subsets of $X$. It is easy to see, that for the subspace $Y$ the subspace topology coincides with the set of all upper subsets of $Y$ with respect to the restricted order. Hence, there is no such example.

Comment: BTW: what is "Alexandroff-discrete" ? And how do you define *the* "Alexandroff topology"?  In this context I would understand this is exactly, what you called upper topology. On the other hand, usually a space is called "Alexandroff", if each element has a minimal neighborhood, i.e. independent of any order. Only in the second step, one then shows that these are exactly the "upper spaces" with respect to a quasiorder.